# SQL creating a log

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a query that gives me a log of hours spend per person per task.

I have the following tables:

- log table with the columns: TaskID, PersonID, Hours
- member table with the columns: ID, Name, Email, Skype, Notes

Eventually the log should look something like this:

```
| Person1 | Task1 | x hours |
| Person1 | Task2 | x hours |
| Person2 | Task1 | x hours |
```

So it has to be grouped by both person and task.

It's the total hours that's giving me trouble.

So far this is what I have:

```
SELECT m.Name, t.Task, Sum(l.Hours) AS TotalHours
FROM Member AS m, Log AS l, Tasks AS t
WHERE t.TaskID=l.TaskID
GROUP BY t.Task, m.Name;
```

However, this gives me a list of unique person-task combinations but with the total amount of hours spend on that task and not the total amount of hours spend on that task per person.

Hopefully I've explained the problem clear enough so that you can help me.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could include your `Member table` within the `where` clause.

So If your `Log table` also includes `MemberId` your Sql Query would read :-

```
Select m.Name, t.Task, Sum(l.Hours) As TotalHours
From Member AS m, Log AS l, Tasks AS t
WHERE t.TaskID=l.TaskID and m.MemberId=l.MemberId
GROUP BY t.Task, m.Name
```

This should give you the results you require.

*Edit :*

If you did want to use explicit rather than implict joins then the Query would read something like the following :-

```
Select m.Name, t.Task, Sum(l.Hours) As TotalHours
From Log AS l
Inner join tasks AS t
On t.TaskID=l.TaskID
Inner join Member AS m
On m.MemberId=l.MemberId
GROUP BY t.Task, m.Name
```

I generally use explicit joins as my queries are considerably larger and I find explicit joins easier to read. As for efficiency and other factors, I am unsure.

Comment: It is nearly always better to use explicit rather than implicit joins, especially in MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join back to your Member table also.  In your posted example you are only joining the Log and Tasks Table.

If you provided some more information about what is in the member's table i'd be happy to assist.

Comment: My member table is as follows:
Member(ID, Name, Email, Skype, Notes)